# Why is the answer “Va bene”?

Tags: grammar, agreement

The answer to

> Come vanno le cose?

is

> Va bene.

So we should answer with incorrect grammar? Isn't it more correct to say "Vanno bene"?

Comment: «The answer ... is Va bene.» Is it? Who says so? It is quite a weird way to answer.

Comment: The standard answer would be “Bene”. If the verb is used it would be “Vanno bene”.

Answer (score 5):

The grammatically correct answer would be *Vanno bene*, but the verb would usually be omitted. Here are some examples:

> — Come vanno le cose? — Bene, grazie.
>   — Come vanno le cose? — Vanno bene, grazie.
>   — Come vanno le cose? — Tutto bene, grazie.
>   — Come vanno le cose? — Va tutto bene, grazie.

Nobody would answer *Va bene* to the question *Come vanno le cose?*. However, as in the third and fourth examples above, the subject can change and so also the verb. In very informal situations, *grazie* would frequently be omitted.